# Retrieve Graph Lowest Height Node with Filter

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, tree, nltk

Given a Tree T, sometimes binary or not, I need to retrieve the lowest Node that matches a criteria in each branch.

So, I need to retrieve a list (array) of those red marked nodes, where they `label` is equal to "NP" `node.label() == 'NP'`.

Actually I'm using NLTK Tree (*nltk.tree.Tree*) data structure, but you can post the pseudocode only, and I can implement it.

[image: Example of Tree]

Here is the code that I've tried:

```
def traverseTree(tree):
  if not isinstance(tree, nltk.Tree): return []
  h = []
  for subtree in tree:
    if type(subtree) == nltk.tree.Tree:
      t = traverseTree(subtree)
      if subtree.label() == 'NP' and len(t) == 0: h.append(subtree)
  return h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a conditional that if the there are no better candidates for your specification then append subtree, but what if `len(t)>0`? in that case you want to keep the  nodes found in sub calls:

```
def traverseTree(tree):
  if not isinstance(tree, nltk.Tree): return []
  h = []
  for subtree in tree:
    if type(subtree) == nltk.tree.Tree:
      t = traverseTree(subtree)
      #RIGHT HERE!! need to extend by t or the other found nodes are thrown out
      h.extend(t)

      if subtree.label() == 'NP' and len(t) == 0:
          h.append(subtree)

  return h
```

Keep in mind that if `t` is always empty you would append all the valid nodes one level below, but any end-of-branch "NP" nodes will be found and returned in `t` so you want to pass them up a level in the recursion.

Edit: the only case where this would fail is if the top level node is "NP" and there are no sub-nodes of "NP" in which case `tree` should be added to `h`:

```
#after for loop has finished
if len(h) == 0 and tree.label() == "NP":
    h.append(tree)
return h
```

edit2: if you add `tree` to `h` then the check for subtrees will never actually come true since they are checking the same node with the same conditionals just in differnt levels of recursion, so you can actually just write the function like this:

```
def traverseTree(tree):
  if not isinstance(tree, nltk.Tree): return []
  h = []
  for subtree in tree:
      #no need to check here as well as right inside the call
      h.extend(traverseTree(subtree))
  if tree.label() == 'NP' and len(h) == 0:
      h.append(tree)
  return h
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right, because I only want to add the nested one, so, if I found any Node above the current `subtree`, I shouldn't add it

Comment: if you found any nodes _above_ the current subtree? You are only ever looking at _subtrees_ so you never check if there is a node above the current one.  Just think about it: `t` represents all the nodes that are 'np' at the bottom of their branches, `if len(t)==0` and subtree.label() == "NP"` then subtree is a valid node, but if `t` is not empty that means there were "np" nodes further down in the branch, and they are stored in `t`.